# Unable to import MongoDB Scala Driver in SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm struggling adding the following dependency to my project's `build.sbt` file...

```
val mongodb  = "org.mongodb.scala"    %% "mongo-scala-driver" % mongodbV
```

Being `mongodbV` "2.5.0".

I've already tried building the project again, invalidating IntellIJ cache and restarting, but I can't find the depedency inside the project and so I can't even import it.

Hope someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: are you not adding `mongodb` to `libraryDependencies`

Comment: @AmitPrasad it is added yeah, that is the strangest part.

Comment: Please share your `libraryDependencies`, because i just did and worked for me.

Comment: @LennyD. It would be better if you can share a complete `build.sbt` file which fails, I'm not saying all your actual file _(because you probably have many things there)_ but a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - that means create a new project only with Scala and Mongo, and see if it fails too and if so, paste that file here, including sbt version and the **error messages** you get. BTW, did you tried it in different locations _(like office, home, college)_ maybe it is a proxy/firewall/internet error.

Answer (score 0):

`build.sbt` should be something like this.

```
  name := "Demo"
  version := "0.1"
  scalaVersion:= "2.12.7"
  val mongodbV = "2.5.0"
  val mongodb  = "org.mongodb.scala"    %% "mongo-scala-driver" % mongodbV
  libraryDependencies += mongodb
```

Hope it helps you.